# COUNT, GROUP BY, and SUM of COUNT in same query

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, sql-order-by

I have a table like this

```
itm_nbr              Owner                    Cost
--------           ---------                ---------
   1                  Gary                      $5   
   2                  Henry                     $12
   3                  Gary                      $3
   4                  Rob                       $5
   5                  Rob                       $31
   6                  Henry                     $20
   7                  Gary                      $1
```

I want to query to find the number of items per owner and the sum of their total item cost which would yield the following result:

```
ItemCount             Owner                    Cost
--------           ---------                ---------
   3                  Gary                      $9  
   2                  Henry                     $22
   2                  Rob                       $36
```

I tried the following query

```
SELECT count(itm_nbr), owner, sum(cost)
FROM table
GROUP BY Owner
ORDER BY Cost
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. As of now your query is invalid because you are trying to sort on a column that is aggregated (`cost`).

You want to sort on the sum of the cost:

```
select 
    count(itm_nbr),
    owner,
    sum(cost)
from table 
group by owner 
order by sum(cost)
```

Or better yet, you can alias all columns and use the alias in the `order by` clause.

```
select 
    count(itm_nbr) cnt_item_nbr,
    owner,
    sum(cost) sum_cost 
from table 
group by owner 
order by sum_cost
```